# Remove table borders between two td completely only in one cell

Tags: html, css

In a large HTML table I have an input part consisting of two adjacent cells. The first one is a right-aligned pound sign and the next one is an input cell (to signal that this part is inputting an amount).

I would like the "double cell" to have red background, but dont seem to be able to remove the white border line between them. As comparison, if you join two cells through colspan, you obviously do not get any separation and I would like to create the same effect for the input cell combo.

Note I do want borders everywhere else in that table, just not between those cells.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:red;text-align:right;padding-right:0;border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;border-spacing:0px;">&pound;</td>
    <td style="background-color:red;padding-left:0;border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;border-spacing:0px;">
      <input type="text" style="background-color:red" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:green" colspan="2">no line</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: add `table {border: none}` to your css code.

Comment: By default, the <input> elements also have a border, which could looks like a table border in you particular case. I recommand disabling input border too.

Comment: Even if the second td is just a straightforward cell (without input) there is still a line that I cant get rid of.

Comment: Word of advise, dont do inline styling make a class or an id and add it into your css.

Comment: As hopefully explained, this question is clearly not a duplicate of the one mentioned above. How do I remove this "duplication" claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the border between `<input>` and `pound` sign, use the pseudo `:before` and make a fake border of the same color (in your case `red`).

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.pound-sign {
  background-color:red;
  text-align:right;
  padding-right:0;
  border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
  border-spacing:0px;
}

.input-holder {
  position: relative;
  background-color:red;
  padding-left:0;
  border-spacing:0px;
}

.input-holder:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -3px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.input-holder input {
  background-color:red;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.green {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="pound-sign" style="">&pound;</td>
    <td class="input-holder">
      <input type="text" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="green" colspan="2">no line</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I only want to remove borders between those two cells, not everywhere in the whole table.

Comment: And I want borders at the other ends of those two cells, just not between the two. So only want to remove one "line".

Comment: @Rob I've updated my answer, have a look. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Looking better, but dont like the table border collapse since this affects all the other cells (just put other rows and cells into this slimmed down test table to see).

Comment: @Rob Oh! my bad. I forgot to remove `border-collapse` property, have a look at the snippet again.

Comment: Even better. Following the comments by Dexter and Options above, can this be tidied up to all just be CSS with classes without the inline styles and without the border on input.

Comment: @Rob Have a look at my updated answer, if this helped you don't forget to upvote & accept.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130526/discussion-between-rob-and-saurav-rastogi).